# Scrape html from js with node.js and horseman

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom, phantomjs

I am trying to scrape the array of batters with salary information from this page:
https://www.swishanalytics.com/optimus/mlb/dfs-batter-projections

I am using node.js and node-horseman.

Here is my code:

```
var Horseman = require('node-horseman');
var horseman = new Horseman();

horseman.open('https://www.swishanalytics.com/optimus/mlb/dfs-batter-projections');

if (horseman.status() === 200) {
    console.log('[+] Successful page opening')
    horseman.screenshot('image.png');
    console.log(horseman.html());
  }    
horseman.close();
```

The issue is the return from horseman.html() is still a lot of JavaScript and cannot be extracted with something like cheerio. How can I execute the javascript programatically?

For example, if I view source at the same link I see that the area that has the batters starts with

```
function Model(){ this.batterArray = 
[{"team_short":"rockies","mlbam_id":"571448","player_name":"Nolan Arenado",
```

Obviously this is still javascript... I'm assuming that at some point it must be executed and converted to HTML to be presented by a browser?

Comment: It can be done with cheerio, I can show you how if you're interested. It'll be easier to use, and return either text or json, but it won't do screenshots like PhantomJS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tested this out and it seems to work:

```
var Horseman = require('node-horseman');
var horseman = new Horseman();

horseman.open('https://www.swishanalytics.com/optimus/mlb/dfs-batter-projections');

if (horseman.status() === 200) {
    console.log('[+] Successful page opening')
    horseman.screenshot('image.png');
    var batters = horseman.evaluate(function(){
        return (new Model()).batterArray;
    });
    console.log(batters);
  }    
horseman.close();
```

That will give you an array of batters that you can use in your code.  You could write it out to a file or create a table out of it.

Comment: Nailed it... I was thinking dead center within the box.

Comment: At the time this did work.  The developer of swishanalytics.com may have changed the page which may have broken this example.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it should work.

```
var Horseman = require('node-horseman');
var horseman = new Horseman();
horseman
 .open('https://www.swishanalytics.com/optimus/mlb/dfs-batter-projections')
 .status()
 .then((status) => {
   if(status === 200){
     console.log('[+] Successful page opening')
     horseman.screenshot('image.png');
     var batters = horseman.evaluate(function(){
       return (new Model()).batterArray;
     });
     console.log(batters);
   }else{
     console.log('no batters');
   }
 })
 .close();
```

Comment: If I call `close` after the status, I get error, similar to this -> https://github.com/johntitus/node-horseman/issues/187
But, .open().close().status().then(function(status){}); Works perfectly fine.